# Can you prove this formula for computing prime numbers is correct?

Tags: prime-numbers

Sometime ago I discovered the following function for computing primes:

$$
Q(x)=\text{frac} \left (\cfrac{\Gamma(x)}{x} \right )\cfrac{x^2}{x-1}= \begin{cases}  x & \small \text{if $x$ is prime} \\  0 & \small \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}  
$$

where "$\text{frac}$" is fractional part and $\Gamma$ is Gamma function.  Is there a way to prove that formula is correct?

Regards

Comment: What about for $x=4$?

Comment: If $x=4$ then you get $\frac{8}{3}$.

Comment: As for the rest of the inputs think about it this way. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$. If $n$ is composite try to prove that $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that the fractional part is $0$. Then tackle the prime case.

Comment: ($n>4$ is composite)

Comment: Hint: Wilson's theorem.

Comment: I forgot to say that function is for integers with $x\ge 5$

Comment: Then why write it using the Gamma function instead of a factorial?

Answer (score 2):

Wilson's theorem: $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)! \equiv -1 \mod n$ iff $n$ is prime.
So if $n$ is prime, $\text{frac}(\Gamma(n)/n = (n-1)/n$.

Suppose $n$ is composite.  For each prime $p$ dividing $n$, if $p^j$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$, then $p^j$ also divides $\Gamma(n)$, and so $\Gamma(n)$ is divisible by $n$, with the sole exception $n = 4 = 2^2$.
Thus if $n \ne 4$, $\text{frac}(\Gamma(n)/n) = 0$.